# How to mute video played in AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

Im playing a video in AVPlayer, and now I need to mute the audio alone while playing it. Please suggest how to do in objective C.

Thanks, 
Suresh

Comment: self.avPlayer.muted = true;

Answer (score 34):

Since iOS7 you can set the AVPlayer `isMuted` property to `true`.

In Objective C the property is called `muted`.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387544-ismuted

Comment: self.avPlayer.muted = true;

Comment: Updated for Swift 3

Answer (score 12):

**For Swift 4 above to make AVPlayer video mute**

```
self.player.isMuted = true
```

Comment: This property does not mute the audio.

Comment: I my case i have tested above code and then posted here.

Answer (score 10):

This should see you through...

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[avPlayer currentItem] asset];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

// Mute all the audio tracks
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

[[avPlayer currentItem] setAudioMix:audioZeroMix];
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but it is not functioning in the simulator. I'm using AVPlayer to play .mov file. Can you suggest any other solution.

Comment: I find that doing it this way interrupts any music you might be playing through Music app or iTunes, etc. Is there a way to continue music playing in the background?

Comment: Great, just change the first "AVURLAsset" to "AVAsset" and it's perfect.

Comment: This looks very complicated, no ?

Answer (score 8):

**SWIFT 2.0 and SWIFT 3.0** *(As of July 5, 2017)*

For those of you curious about Swift it is simply just:

```
self.avPlayer.muted = true
```

EASIEST way for OBJECTIVE-C:

```
self.avPlayer.muted = true;
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working for you Vineesh. It's working on my Swift 3.0 and 3.1. Could it be other variables you have going there?

Answer (score 3):

`player.isMuted = true` is not working for me.

In my case I need the video permanently mute. So I used the below code to achieve this.

```
self.player.volume = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set muted false when the video is playing status.

add listener:

```
[itemPlayer addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:kStatusKey
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:@"AVPlayerStatus"];
```

code:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)path ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == @"AVPlayerStatus") {
        AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
        switch (status) {
            case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay: {
                if (isMuted) {
                    layerPlayer.player.muted = true;
                }
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**iOS mute/unmute audio**

iOS devise has Silent mode. When [Silent mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphb71f9b54d/ios) is On(red dot) by default device doesn't play audio.

When you open system's Photo app you find that:

- Live Photo's sound is bounded with Silent mode. E.g when Silent mode is on, video's audio is off
- Video's sound is not bounded with Silent mode. It is muted by default but you are able to change it(unmute) even when Silent mode is on

As for AVPlayer

You are able to change [`AVPlayer.isMuted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387544-ismuted) property

```
self.player.isMuted = true
```

By default it is bounded with Silent mode. To play audio when Silent mode is on set audio playback category(e.g when app is started)

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
} catch {
    
}
```

Also check that `AVLayer.volume` is not zero to hear an audio track