# How to mute video recording in custom camera in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating the custom camera for video recording using `AVCam` of apple,but i want implement the functionality to mute the video while recording, can any body has any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try With Following code From:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120687/how-to-mute-video-played-in-avplayer)

```
 AVURLAsset *asset = [[avPlayer currentItem] asset];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

// Mute all the audio tracks
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
    [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

[[avPlayer currentItem] setAudioMix:audioZeroMix];
```

**Other way is**

Read this question [AVFoundation, how to turn off the shutter sound when captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401232/avfoundation-how-to-turn-off-the-shutter-sound-when-capturestillimageasynchrono)